# Selenium WebDriver jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm very new to Selenium WebDriver and I'm learning how to use jQuery selectors to work with elements instead of using XPath expressions, IDs, etc...

Could you please help me by providing a link where I can find some basic information on how to use jQuery in Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: I don't think selectors change on a different framework .. It would be the same

Comment: thanks. But some of my selector using xpath, id is not working all the browsers. and i googled it and got a information. Using JQUERY will solve all the problems. So i thought of learning Javascriptexecutor

Comment: What did Googling tell you? I google "selenium jquery" and get a ton of results, especially a number of stack overflow posts and b) Why exactly do you need to use jQuery? I understand in some cases, but in 99% of cases, you should get away with the native locators. What isn't working? Why? How is it not working? Have you tried CSS & XPath selectors? If yes, why didn't they work? What did you use? Show us some code. What went wrong. How it went wrong. What you expected to happen.

Comment: First Google result page gives me enough answers already. But the real question is are you even going to the right direction? If you can still convince yourself that you need to use JQuery after answering all Arran's questions, we can then continue.

Comment: Thanks!. The indent of this question is to learn how to use JQUERY in the Selenium Webdriver. I just want to know is there any link for the beginners to start learning how to use jquery in Selenium Webdriver. At what scenarios we should use? etc..

Answer (score 11):

You shoudn't. JQuery selectors offer most of what CSS 2 and CSS 3 selectors do, plus something more, but you can probably live without it. If you know JQuery selectors, you already know CSS selectors.

Use CSS selectors where you can and use XPath expressions where it's not enough (they're stronger). I doubt you'll find many real usages where these two aren't enough (and then, the usual approach is to get what you can and iterate over the collection, filtering the results manually).

---

That said, you could possibly force WebDriver to accept JQuery selectors, too:

If you only want to support one or two browsers, the easiest way might be to write a simple addon to that browser which would inject JQuery to every page if it's not already present. You'd then force this addon to be used by the browser you're using.

If you want to support all of the browsers, that solution quickly becomes a burden and the best you could do is to write a decorator for WebDriver that would try to inject JQuery into the page before any `findElements()` and/or `executeScript()` call, if it's not already present.

See [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/webdriver-can-i-inject-a-jquery-script-for-a-page-that-isnt-using-jquery) to get an idea about injecting JQuery.

After you've injected it, you can use it, again, only via JavaScript:

```
// earlier
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This driver cannot run JavaScript.");
}

WebElement element = (WebElement)js.executeScript("$('div.account').get(0)");
// or
List<WebElement> elements = (List<WebElement>)js.executeScript("$('div.account').get()");
```

You can easily wrap those lines into a new `By` object, or a new `findElement(String jQuerySelector)` method for your decorated WebDriver, if you want, but that's up to your convenience and laziness, we got it working...

---

The best approach, I think, would be to create a new `By` implementation called `ByJQuery`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460561/1273080) on how to make a `ByJavaScript` - it's a small step from there to reuse it, inject JQuery into the page and run the actual query.

```
class ByJQuery extends By implements Serializable {
    private final String query;

    public ByJQuery(String query) {
        checkNotNull(query, "Cannot find elements with a null JQuery expression.");
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
        WebDriver driver = getWebDriverFromSearchContext(context);

        if (!isJQueryInThisPage(driver)) {
            injectJQuery(driver);
        }

        return new ByJavaScript("return $(" + query + ")").findElements(context);
    }

    private static WebDriver getWebDriverFromSearchContext(SearchContext context) {
        if (context instanceof WebDriver) {
            return (WebDriver)context;
        }
        if (context instanceof WrapsDriver) {
            return ((WrapsDriver)context).getWrappedDriver();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't access a WebDriver instance from the current search context.");
    }

    private static boolean isJQueryInThisPage(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Some JavaScript test for a JQuery object.
    }

    private static void injectJQuery(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Load JQuery from a file, inject it into the page via JS.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "By.jQuery: \"$(" + query + ")\"";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Only thing I found wrong with it was that there isn't any quotes in the JQuery selector. I had to change it to read `return new ByJavaScript( "return $(\"" + query + "\")" ).findElements( context );` Obviously then you need to be aware the initial quotes are double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

iWebdriver jQuery Extension, This will work across all browsers. Copy and paste to your webdriver extension.

```
  public static IWebElement FindByTextJQuery(this IWebDriver driver, string Tagname, string Text)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        bool flag = (bool)js.ExecuteScript("return typeof jQuery == 'undefined'");
        if (flag)
        {
            js.ExecuteScript("var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);");
        }
        driver.WaitForAjax();
        js.ExecuteScript("$('" + Tagname + ":contains(" + Text + ")').css('background-color', '')");
        IWebElement elements = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(@"return $('"+Tagname+":contains("+Text+")')[0]");
        return elements;
    }

 public static string getTextByJquery(this IWebDriver driver, string jquery)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        string elementsText = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $('" + jquery +    "').text()");
        return elementsText;
    }

 public static int returnIndexByJquery(this IWebDriver driver, string jQuery)
    {

        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        bool flag = (bool)js.ExecuteScript("return typeof jQuery == 'undefined'");
        if (flag)
        {
            js.ExecuteScript("var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);");
        }
        driver.WaitForAjax();
      //  js.ExecuteScript(@"return $('" + Tagname + ":contains(" + Text + ")').css('background-color', 'blue')");
        Int64 elementIndex = (Int64)js.ExecuteScript(@"return $('"+jQuery+"').index()[0]");
        return Convert.ToInt32(elementIndex);                     
    }

   public static int returnCountByJquery(this IWebDriver driver, string jQuery)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        bool flag = (bool)js.ExecuteScript("return typeof jQuery == 'undefined'");
        if (flag)
        {
            js.ExecuteScript("var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);");
        }
        driver.WaitForAjax();
        //  js.ExecuteScript(@"return $('" + Tagname + ":contains(" + Text + ")').css('background-color', 'blue')");
        Int64 elementCount = (Int64)js.ExecuteScript(@"return $('" + jQuery + "').size()");
        return Convert.ToInt32(elementCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `find_element_by_css_selector()` and it gives me all I need.

According to [this blog post](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/01/why-jquery-in-selenium-css-locators-is-the-way-to-go/comment-page-1/), selenium uses the same css engine as jquery does.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code block for using the click action to the element selecting with the jquery selector

1) .overlay-selector-indicator.ui-draggable.selected-overlay.ui-resizable

```
Webdriver driver = new SafariDriver();  
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("$('.overlay-selector-indicator.ui-draggable.selected-overlay.ui-resizable').click();", "");
```

You can use any jquery selector instead of 1. and can use any event in place of click().