# How can I extend the Selenium By.class to create more flexibility?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How can I extend the Selenium **By.class** to create more flexibility?   I looked at the [By.class](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java) and I don't quite know how to approach this.   It looks like I need to create an interface class and a static By class, such as **ByJavascriptGetWebElement**, in order to create this kind of wrapper?

I would like to be able to call it like:

```
By.javascript("return document.querySelector(\"div#item div\");", el );
```

And I have also heard of an easier way to do it but I would prefer to do it the more traditional way:

```
public By byJavascriptGetElement( WebElement we ) {
    return By.  ???
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can actually be easily done.

The idea is to get access to the `WebDriver` instance and run the JavaScript on it (if it supports it). Then there's a lot of validating, because we need to make sure we only return what we promised.

The `ByJavaScript` class itself will look like this:

```
public class ByJavaScript extends By implements Serializable {
    private final String script;

    public ByJavaScript(String script) {
        checkNotNull(script, "Cannot find elements with a null JavaScript expression.");
        this.script = script;
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = getJavascriptExecutorFromSearchContext(context);

        // call the JS, inspect and validate response
        Object response = js.executeScript(script);
        List<WebElement> elements = getElementListFromJsResponse(response);

        // filter out the elements that aren't descendants of the context node
        if (context instanceof WebElement) {
            filterOutElementsWithoutCommonAncestor(elements, (WebElement)context);
        }

        return elements;
    }

    private static JavascriptExecutor getJavascriptExecutorFromSearchContext(SearchContext context) {
        if (context instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            // context is most likely the whole WebDriver
            return (JavascriptExecutor)context;
        }
        if (context instanceof WrapsDriver) {
            // context is most likely some WebElement
            WebDriver driver = ((WrapsDriver)context).getWrappedDriver();
            checkState(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor, "This WebDriver doesn't support JavaScript.");
            return (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("We can't invoke JavaScript from this context.");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // cast thoroughly checked
    private static List<WebElement> getElementListFromJsResponse(Object response) {
        if (response == null) {
            // no element found
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }
        if (response instanceof WebElement) {
            // a single element found
            return Lists.newArrayList((WebElement)response);
        }
        if (response instanceof List) {
            // found multiple things, check whether every one of them is a WebElement
            checkArgument(
                    Iterables.all((List<?>)response, Predicates.instanceOf(WebElement.class)),
                    "The JavaScript query returned something that isn't a WebElement.");
            return (List<WebElement>)response;  // cast is checked as far as we can tell
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The JavaScript query returned something that isn't a WebElement.");
    }

    private static void filterOutElementsWithoutCommonAncestor(List<WebElement> elements, WebElement ancestor) {
        for (Iterator<WebElement> iter = elements.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            WebElement elem = iter.next();

            // iterate over ancestors
            while (!elem.equals(ancestor) && !elem.getTagName().equals("html")) {
                elem = elem.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
            }

            if (!elem.equals(ancestor)) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
          return "By.javaScript: \"" + script + "\"";
    }

}
```

<sup>This code uses [the Google Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/). It is a dependency of Selenium, so you should have it on your classpath. But if there's something you don't understand, look into Guava.</sup>

Things to consider:

1. Document the whole thing.
2. Use better and more helpful exceptions. Consider some custom subclasses of `WebDriverException`. Also add more helpful messages and info.
3. Restrict the class' visibility to package. Or embed it into a static factory (as seen in the original `By` class) so that it won't be accessible directly etc.
4. Write tests. I have tried the most obvious usages (element can't be found, search from driver, search from some context) and everything seems to be ok, but I didn't test it extensively.

Usage:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(new ByJavaScript("return document.querySelector('.haha');"));
```

Now, the original `By` class is a static factory that gives out various implementations of itself. Unfortunately, we can't add a new static method to it (without changing its source), so we won't be able to type `By.javascript("return something;")`. We have to create our own static factory to get something similar:

```
public class MyBy {
    /**
     * Returns a {@code By} which locates elements by the JavaScript expression passed to it.
     * 
     * @param script The JavaScript expression to run and whose result to return
     */
    public static By javascript(String script) {
        return new ByJavaScript(script);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(MyBy.javascript("return document.querySelector('.haha');"));
```

Comment: Thanks Slanec.  That is the answer I was looking for.   There is a whole bunch of stuff in your answer that makes sense but I would have not thought of it without spending many hours of time.  I appreciate your great and thoughtful answer.

Comment: No problem. I like spreading knowledge! If you had any additional questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Neat.  Would be useful I think to write a more specific class, such as 'ByJquery'.

Comment: @djangofan Yeah. Like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555280/selenium-webdriver-jquery ? :)